# Does Apache Kylo support IoT data consumption?

Tags: data-transfer, streaming

I manually setup a Kylo on my linux recently and tried some data pipelines on it including raw data and real-time streams. Results were as expected!

> Curious about IoT support of Kylo

Did anyone successfully consume streaming data coming from an Internet-of-things (IoT) source?

I am a newbie to IoT, looking where to start!

> Does Kylo even support consuming sensors data?

Comment: "Results were as expected!" - but you are not going to tell us what you expected, so that we can amuse ourselves by guessing?

Comment: Could you please define what you mean by "streaming"?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and since Kylo is based on top off [Apache NiFi](https://nifi.apache.org), you can start with NiFi documentation.

Great starting point for Apache NiFi can be **[Apache  NiFi Videos](http://nifi.apache.org/videos.html)**
and video **Build a Simple Flow - Part1**

Good references are [Apache NiFi JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NIFI) pages. 
All what you have to do in first step is to create three(3) basic processor objects:

1) Receiving yours sensor data on TCP/HTTP [ListenHTTP Processor]

2) Transferring yours incoming JSON into SQL statements [ConvertJSONtoSQL Processor]

3) [PutSQL Processor] can write all data received into yours MySQl/PostgreSQL database.

[image: NiFi screen shot]

In addition, I would advise very nice online presentation on this [LINK](https://www.slideshare.net/Hadoop_Summit/realtime-ingesting-and-transforming-sensor-data-and-social-data-with-nifi-and-tensorflow).